# Magnetic force of attracting wires

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Two wires with equal current attract each other, but electrons in the wires are moving with same speed (since currents are equal) and are relatively at rest. Then how is the magnetic field produced and the wires attracted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the rest frame of the electrons the protons are moving.

Comment: but protons are also relatively rest with respect to other protons

Answer (score 0):

Current creates a magnetic field through one of the four “fundamental interactions of the universe”, namely the electromagnetic force. This manifests as electrical attraction/repulsion between two or more charges, and as magnetic attraction/repulsion between two or more currents.

Even though they appear to be two distinct types of forces, they both arise from a single quantum tensor - the electromagnetic tensor.

The equivalence becomes more clear when studying relativity and seeing that what is an electric field in one frame is a magnetic filed in another frame. The electric field as seen from the electron (which you mentioned is at rest in its own frame) is a magnetic field to us.

Comment: I answered your question. If that’s not helpful shouldnt have asked.